# How to select input types text and search on body blur in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following snippet working fine:

```
$(function(){

    //trim all input-text fields and remove extra spaces
    $('body').on('blur',':text',function(){
        var newVal=$(this).val().trim();
        $(this).val( newVal.replace( /\s+/g, ' ' ) );
    });

});
```

Problem is that I need to also select *search* input fields too, I've tried the following without success:

```
':text,:search'
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no selector like `:search` , so you can use attribute selector **[`[type=search]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** instead

```
$(function(){
    //trim all input-text fields and remove extra spaces
    $('body').on('blur','[type=search],:text',function(){
        var newVal=$(this).val().trim();
        $(this).val( newVal.replace( /\s+/g, ' ' ) );
    });
 });
```

Valid selectors : https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Why is it that I cannot use `:search`? is it because it's a new HTML5 type ?

Comment: Got it. `:search` is not a selector as it's not listed here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/